# symfony DIC 3.0 prototype services

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony

*Prototype service means service, which is passed as dependency as always new fresh instance.
In the end its similar to cloning the dependency in instance where its required, but its clean solution.*

As writen [on Symfony news Twitter](https://twitter.com/symfony_en/status/613653805280927744), scopes was officially deprecated.
prototype services was set up by scopes.

**How can i set prototype services in Symfony DIC 3.0 configuration?**
(I prefer yml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the [upgrade 2.7 to 2.8](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/50e752b8624a03844f9b5f9e2ff37fbb293138c1/UPGRADE-2.8.md#dependencyinjection) it says that the `scope: prototype` flag has been changed to `shared: false`.

*Taken from the upgrade file....*

A new shared flag has been added to the service definition in replacement of the prototype scope.

**Before:**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container
    ->register('foo', 'stdClass')
    ->setScope(ContainerBuilder::SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
;

services:
    foo:
        class: stdClass
        scope: prototype

<services>
    <service id="foo" class="stdClass" scope="prototype" />
</services>
```

**After:**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container
    ->register('foo', 'stdClass')
    ->setShared(false)
;

services:
    foo:
        class: stdClass
        shared: false

<services>
    <service id="foo" class="stdClass" shared="false" />
</services>
```