# What is the lifespan of the service container?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to understand the Symfony2 framework.

Coming from a Java/Spring background, I realized Scope in Symfony2 is different from Scope in Spring. Moreover, with Symfony3, [Scope is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31068389/1435070), but we can specify whether a service is shared or not.

What does this mean?

Will the service object be preserved by the service container until its lifespan? Does that mean I can use member variables to hold stateful information across requests? (I'm not sure if that is really possible because apparently that does *not* happen).

So it probably does not span across requests. Does the service container's lifespan equal the request? Because I notice if I have a dependency used by two consumers, if I set `shared: false`, each consumer gets a different "state" of the dependency. But they're essentially in the same request.

What does specifying `shared: false` really mean? Or what does `shared: true` mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lifetime for service is single request.

Shared service means that same instance will be returned every time when service is accessed. If you set `shared: false` then new instance of service will be created every time you ask for service.

You also mentioned 2 consumers. I believe that you run your consumers as separated processes so these are different requests and different scopes.

Comment: When you say >>"Shared service means that same instance will be returned every time when service is accessed", do you mean in the same request - because they're as i understand part of the same service container? By 2 consumers i meant 1 is a controller which accesses a dependency D1 method directly and also accesses D1 via D2. I observed both were different states when `shared` was `false`. But same state when `shared` was `true`.

Comment: Yes, I mean "in the same request". Symfony does not share anything between requests (except if store something explicitly in cookies, sessions, some database or any other storage).

Comment: Seeing my trials and your response, i'll mark the answer as accepted. Thank you. I have another question - if we can specify a service as shared using annotations. But i guess that warrants another question here.

Comment: All services are shared by default.

Answer (score 5):

Although Mantas is right in most cases, stating that the lifetime is a single request might be misleading in some edge cases.

Basically, the service container lives as long as the Kernel lives. The service container is initialised during `Kernel::boot()` which is called the first time the Kernel handles a request. (See for example your front end controller, app.php.) The container is thrown away on `Kernel::shutdown()` or when the PHP process exits.

So, when you let your Kernel handle multiple requests, or whenever you do subrequests during the lifespan of your Kernel, the service container still exists and any state in your services is preserved.

Take for example the following two code snippets:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

$responseOne = $kernel->handle($requestOne); // Container initialised
$responseOne->send();
$kernel->terminate($requestOne, $responseOne);

$responseTwo = $kernel->handle($requestTwo); // Container still exists
$responseTwo->send();
$kernel->terminate($requestTwo, $responseTwo);

$kernel->shutdown(); // Container destructed
```

And

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

$responseOne = $kernel->handle($requestOne); // Container initialised
$responseOne->send();
$kernel->terminate($requestOne, $responseOne);
$kernel->shutdown(); // Container destructed

$responseTwo = $kernel->handle($requestTwo); // New Container initialised
$responseTwo->send();
$kernel->terminate($requestTwo, $responseTwo);
// PHP exits, container destructed
```

In most cases your PHP proces will have the lifespan of one request to your webserver. However, there are situations in which you can leverage the ability to keep the kernel including the service container alive between requests. For instance, there is the [php-pm project](https://github.com/php-pm/php-pm) which basically keeps your kernel alive and fires requests at it.

This will allow for a big performance improvement (there is no overhead of building a container and initialising bundles over and over again for each request). On the other hand, your services will be shared for multiple requests and probably for multiple users which means that saving state in your services might impose a big security risk.

Therefore, always separate your data classes from your services and don't store data in your services. Symfony is a good example, it separates data using the Request and Response classes.